# Remove all characters between two words and replace with a space

Tags: python, cisco

I'm using Python 3. I've written two programs. One loops through a csv file to obtain IP addresses for Cisco switches, logs in, runs a command, and outputs to results for each to an individual text file. So I end up with a number of text files...one for each switch. The second program uses xlwt to write the information in each text file to its own sheet in Excel.

The main idea is that I need to develop a report showing ports in and out of service. Once I get these imported into Excel I can write some formulas to extract the data I need. But as it stands now when I import this into Excel I have to manually remove some of the cells because everything doesn't line up and that's because of the spaces in between some of the words in the name column (I'm importing into Excel as space delimited). I've attempted to do some things with string and list methods (split, join, slicing, etc) but I'm not able to get exactly what I want. And the Name column is not standardized in any kind of consistent convention. I do notice that although the name may actually be very long, it gets truncated to a certain number of characters.

Ideally, removing the first 4 lines (there is blank line at the very top) and the last line first, then for anythting between Port and Status, remove it all (remove the column altogether including the header).

This is how the files look after getting data from the switch.

```
sw1#term length 0
sw1#show interfaces status

Port      Name               Status       Vlan       Duplex  Speed Type
Gi0/1     Trunk to switch (a connected    1          a-full  a-100 10/100/1000BaseTX
Gi0/2     Network augment pe connected    1          a-full a-1000 10/100/1000BaseTX
Gi0/3                        connected    1          a-full a-1000 10/100/1000BaseTX
Gi0/4                        connected    1          a-full  a-100 10/100/1000BaseTX
Gi0/5                        notconnect   1            auto   auto Not Present
Gi0/6                        notconnect   1            auto   auto Not Present
Gi0/7                        notconnect   1            auto   auto Not Present
Gi0/8                        notconnect   1            auto   auto Not Present
Gi0/9                        notconnect   1            auto   auto Not Present
Gi0/10                       connected    1          a-full  a-100 10/100/1000BaseTX
Gi0/11                       notconnect   1            auto   auto Not Present
Gi0/12                       connected    1          a-full  a-100 10/100/1000BaseTX
Gi0/13                       disabled     1            auto   auto Not Present
Gi0/14                       disabled     1            auto   auto Not Present
Gi0/15                       disabled     1            auto   auto Not Present
Gi0/16                       disabled     1            auto   auto Not Present
sw1#logout
```

End result I'd like below. This should allow the row/column structure to remain intact when importing into Excel. Note that all of the column info is separated by spaces. I've found that importing as fixed width or delimited by space with treat consecutive spaces as one checked seems to work pretty well.

```
Port      Status       Vlan       Duplex  Speed Type
Gi0/1     connected    1          a-full  a-100 10/100/1000BaseTX
Gi0/2     connected    1          a-full a-1000 10/100/1000BaseTX
Gi0/3     connected    1          a-full a-1000 10/100/1000BaseTX
Gi0/4     connected    1          a-full  a-100 10/100/1000BaseTX
Gi0/5     notconnect   1            auto   auto Not Present
Gi0/6     notconnect   1            auto   auto Not Present
Gi0/7     notconnect   1            auto   auto Not Present
Gi0/8     notconnect   1            auto   auto Not Present
Gi0/9     notconnect   1            auto   auto Not Present
Gi0/10    connected    1          a-full  a-100 10/100/1000BaseTX
Gi0/11    notconnect   1            auto   auto Not Present
Gi0/12    connected    1          a-full  a-100 10/100/1000BaseTX
Gi0/13    disabled     1            auto   auto Not Present
Gi0/14    disabled     1            auto   auto Not Present
Gi0/15    disabled     1            auto   auto Not Present
Gi0/16    disabled     1            auto   auto Not Present
```

Any pointers would be appreciated. I'm thinking regular expressions may be in order but I need a bit assistance with how to construct that. I hope this isn't too ambiguous.

**REMOVED A PREVIOUS UPDATE AND MOVED IT TO A NEW THREAD**

Comment: Post the code you have so far. Initial thought is that `split()` is fully capabable of handling this; just skip everything after index `0` until the the word "connected|notconnected|disabled" shows up; after that everything lookks pretty aligned to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open('file') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    lines = lines[-1:] + lines[2:-1]
    for line in lines:
        print line[0:11] + line[35:-1]
```

i think that will do roughly what you want; you may need to play with the numbers a little as i haven't run it myself.  all it uses is list (or string) indexing:

- list[x:] is all entries from x onwards
- list[x:y] is all entries from x to y
- list[-x] is the xth line from the end

the `lines[-1:] + lines[2:-1]` puts the last line first, and throws away the first two; `line[0:11] + line[35:-1]` excludes the part you don't want and the final newline.

**update** if you want to write into a new file, instead of stdout:

```
with open('infile') as in:
    with open('outfile', 'w') as out:
        lines = in.readlines()
        ...
            print(line[0:6] + line[28:-1], file=out)
```

in fact, since readlines reads everything at once, you could do:

```
with open('infile') as in:
    lines = in.readlines()
with open('outfile', 'w') as out:
    for line in lines:
        ....
        print(line[0:6] + line[28:-1], file=out)
```

as there's no need for the input file to be open (it's closed when the `with` finishes).

Comment: This one works pretty good as well. For the files I'm working with the line print (line[0:6] + line[28:-1]) is good. Now to just get this into a new file.

Comment: Works good. I had to make a few changes to the indexes which I'm not sure why. I'm using the same input file for every change that I test. I suspect it has to do with the \n's I see when I print to stdout. In anycase, works well and removes the first and last lines of the file and works well in Excel.

Comment: an alternative to removing the last `\n` is to use strip: `line = line.strip()` which removes the newline and any trailing/starting spaces.  then you won't need to drop the last character.

Comment: Andrew, I've worked on this a bit a posted an update...would mind taking a look and respond if you have any suggestions?

Comment: is this about the `,,` question?  just pull out that section, like the others, but call `.strip()` on the string.  that removes leading and trailing spaces so will shrink the blocks with no data down to nothing.

Comment: thanks for responding. i figured out what to do and now am getting the results i need. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

As a start, the code below removes the name-column. Take it from there and add a nice csv printout. HINT: `column[-1]` is the last entry and `column[-2]` second to last. Join these if the string `Not` is present...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

tokens = ['connected', 'notconnect', 'disabled']

with open('text') as fd:
    for line in fd:
        line = line.strip().split()

        connection = [line[0]]
        found = False

        for i in line:
            if i in tokens:
                found = True
            if found:
                connection.append(i)

        print connection
```

output:

```
['Gi0/1', 'connected', '1', 'a-full', 'a-100', '10/100/1000BaseTX']
['Gi0/2', 'connected', '1', 'a-full', 'a-1000', '10/100/1000BaseTX']
['Gi0/3', 'connected', '1', 'a-full', 'a-1000', '10/100/1000BaseTX']
['Gi0/4', 'connected', '1', 'a-full', 'a-100', '10/100/1000BaseTX']
['Gi0/5', 'notconnect', '1', 'auto', 'auto', 'Not', 'Present']
['Gi0/6', 'notconnect', '1', 'auto', 'auto', 'Not', 'Present']
['Gi0/7', 'notconnect', '1', 'auto', 'auto', 'Not', 'Present']
['Gi0/8', 'notconnect', '1', 'auto', 'auto', 'Not', 'Present']
['Gi0/9', 'notconnect', '1', 'auto', 'auto', 'Not', 'Present']
['Gi0/10', 'connected', '1', 'a-full', 'a-100', '10/100/1000BaseTX']
['Gi0/11', 'notconnect', '1', 'auto', 'auto', 'Not', 'Present']
['Gi0/12', 'connected', '1', 'a-full', 'a-100', '10/100/1000BaseTX']
['Gi0/13', 'disabled', '1', 'auto', 'auto', 'Not', 'Present']
['Gi0/14', 'disabled', '1', 'auto', 'auto', 'Not', 'Present']
['Gi0/15', 'disabled', '1', 'auto', 'auto', 'Not', 'Present']
['Gi0/16', 'disabled', '1', 'auto', 'auto', 'Not', 'Present']
```

## Update after comment:

This is how I'd do it using the [KISS principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

tokens = ['connected', 'notconnect', 'disabled']

with open('text') as fd:
    for line in fd:
        line = line.strip().split()

        connection = [line[0]]
        found = False

        for i in line:
            if i in tokens:
                found = True
            if found:
                connection.append(i)

        if 'Not' in connection and 'Present' in connection:
            # Remove last 2 entries
            connection.pop() ; connection.pop()
            connection.append('Not Present')

        print connection
```

output:

```
['Gi0/1', 'connected', '1', 'a-full', 'a-100', '10/100/1000BaseTX']
['Gi0/2', 'connected', '1', 'a-full', 'a-1000', '10/100/1000BaseTX']
['Gi0/3', 'connected', '1', 'a-full', 'a-1000', '10/100/1000BaseTX']
['Gi0/4', 'connected', '1', 'a-full', 'a-100', '10/100/1000BaseTX']
['Gi0/5', 'notconnect', '1', 'auto', 'auto', 'Not Present']
['Gi0/6', 'notconnect', '1', 'auto', 'auto', 'Not Present']
['Gi0/7', 'notconnect', '1', 'auto', 'auto', 'Not Present']
['Gi0/8', 'notconnect', '1', 'auto', 'auto', 'Not Present']
['Gi0/9', 'notconnect', '1', 'auto', 'auto', 'Not Present']
['Gi0/10', 'connected', '1', 'a-full', 'a-100', '10/100/1000BaseTX']
['Gi0/11', 'notconnect', '1', 'auto', 'auto', 'Not Present']
['Gi0/12', 'connected', '1', 'a-full', 'a-100', '10/100/1000BaseTX']
['Gi0/13', 'disabled', '1', 'auto', 'auto', 'Not Present']
['Gi0/14', 'disabled', '1', 'auto', 'auto', 'Not Present']
['Gi0/15', 'disabled', '1', 'auto', 'auto', 'Not Present']
['Gi0/16', 'disabled', '1', 'auto', 'auto', 'Not Present']
```

Comment: I have your solution working as you have explained but when I try to join 'Not', 'Present' I'm not able to figure it out. I can do something similar to ' '.join(line[-2:]) but I can't get it to work for all lines. Also, and this is probably obvious to you, I end up with 'Not Present' and everything else removed. I've tried for loop and several join exercises so it'a not completely foreign. I just can't seem to duplicate what you did to remove the name column. Can you give me another pointer?

Comment: @Shane - Updated, sorry for late response!

Comment: Thank you for your time. This works great. I learned so much trying to do this so even though I couldn't get myself I will take away a lot. I tried so many different things. It's really cool to see that there are many ways to do things with Python. By the way I'm looking to incorporate your solution using csv because I found while a combination of some of the other solutions worked depending on the switch type there were more or less characters to deal with in each column. Your method involves working with csv so I think will work better.

Comment: as soon as I earn enough reputation points I'll come back and upvote because it was definitely helpful.

Comment: Fredrik, I've posted an update and would be interested in any input you may have.

Comment: @Shane - start a new thread. This one is accepted and people don't tend to look at those as frequently...

Comment: i was going to start a new thread as you suggested but figured i would try a few more things on my own first. and i am able to format the file the way i want it. just wanted to let you know as you spent a little time on this and i've implemented some of your suggestions. and i've gotten more efficient with the amount of code i use too. i cut it down almost in half. thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I skipped first 3 lines:

```
sw1#term length 0
sw1#show interfaces status
```

**program:**

```
with open('in.txt') as f,open('out.txt','w') as out:
   line1=f.readline()
   ind1=line1.find('Name')
   ind2=line1.find('Status')
   x=line1.split()
   x.remove('Name')
   y="%-13s %-15s %-6s %-7s %-8s %-s"%(x[0],x[1],x[2],x[3],x[4],x[5])
   out.write(y+'\n')
   for x in f:
       x=x[:ind1]+x[ind2:]
       x=x.split()
       y="%-13s %-15s %-6s %-7s %-8s %-s"%(x[0],x[1],x[2],x[3],x[4],x[5])
       out.write(y+'\n')


Port          Status          Vlan   Duplex  Speed    Type
Gi0/1         connected       1      a-full  a-100    10/100/1000BaseTX
Gi0/2         connected       1      a-full  a-1000   10/100/1000BaseTX
Gi0/3         connected       1      a-full  a-1000   10/100/1000BaseTX
Gi0/4         connected       1      a-full  a-100    10/100/1000BaseTX
Gi0/5         notconnect      1      auto    auto     Not
Gi0/6         notconnect      1      auto    auto     Not
Gi0/7         notconnect      1      auto    auto     Not
Gi0/8         notconnect      1      auto    auto     Not
Gi0/9         notconnect      1      auto    auto     Not
Gi0/10        connected       1      a-full  a-100    10/100/1000BaseTX
Gi0/11        notconnect      1      auto    auto     Not
Gi0/12        connected       1      a-full  a-100    10/100/1000BaseTX
Gi0/13        disabled        1      auto    auto     Not
Gi0/14        disabled        1      auto    auto     Not
Gi0/15        disabled        1      auto    auto     Not
Gi0/16        disabled        1      auto    auto     Not
```

Comment: I've been working with several of the solutions offered here but this one I seem to be able to duplicate and produce good results with. But I can't write the results to a file. Usually, and because this is all I know, I open a file for writing and do the typical for line in f: f.write(line). Or some iteration of that construct. I've gotten pretty good at opening an existing file and writing some of its content to a new file. 

In this case, the variable x contains the data I want to write to file. So something like for line i x: open('newfile', 'w').write(x)  ?

Comment: I appreciate everyone's reponses and obviously I'm a novice but this is a great learning opportunity for me. From the suggestions I've gotten so far I see just how much I have yet to learn.

Comment: @Shane I edited the solution, now the output will be written to a text file.

Comment: Ah I see. With this edit you store the result in y and can write it from there. I was trying to write x after the x=x.split(). And I didn't know could open and write to files on the 'fly' like that. Cool. It's also interesting that you don't have to close the files. This code does work and importing into Excel looks good.

Comment: I've posted an update, would you mind reviewing and offering any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Let's just take the first and the 5 last values and do a little case switch if the type is not present:

```
print "{:10} {:15} {:5} {:6} {:6} {}".format("port", "status", "vlan", "duplex", "speed", "type")
with open(my_filename) as logfile:
    content = logfile.read()
    for line in content.splitlines()[4:]:
        port = line.split()[0]
        if line.strip().endswith("Not Present"):
            itype = "Not Present"
            status, vlan, duplex, speed = line.split()[-6:-2]
        else:
            status, vlan, duplex, speed, itype = line.split()[-5:]
        print "{:10} {:15} {:5} {:6} {:6} {}".format(port, status, vlan, duplex, speed, itype)
```

Yields:

```
port       status          vlan  duplex speed  type            
Gi0/1      connected       1     a-full a-100  10/100/1000BaseTX
Gi0/2      connected       1     a-full a-1000 10/100/1000BaseTX
Gi0/3      connected       1     a-full a-1000 10/100/1000BaseTX
Gi0/4      connected       1     a-full a-100  10/100/1000BaseTX
Gi0/5      notconnect      1     auto   auto   Not Present
Gi0/6      notconnect      1     auto   auto   Not Present
Gi0/7      notconnect      1     auto   auto   Not Present
Gi0/8      notconnect      1     auto   auto   Not Present
Gi0/9      notconnect      1     auto   auto   Not Present
Gi0/10     connected       1     a-full a-100  10/100/1000BaseTX
Gi0/11     notconnect      1     auto   auto   Not Present
Gi0/12     connected       1     a-full a-100  10/100/1000BaseTX
Gi0/13     disabled        1     auto   auto   Not Present
Gi0/14     disabled        1     auto   auto   Not Present
Gi0/15     disabled        1     auto   auto   Not Present
Gi0/16     disabled        1     auto   auto   Not Present
```